# How to prevent Iframe video go beyond max-width & max-height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, youtube-iframe-api

I embedded a responsive youtube video with bootstrap.

My aim: keep it's max size `width="560" height="315"` which is then centered.

How it should be: https://avexdesigns.com/responsive-youtube-embed/

But instead it goes beyond these limits, making the video very blurry.

How it should not be: https://bomengeduld.github.io/mos-man2/

So far I tryed to set max-width & max-height in css, but it only adjusts the width.

What Am I Doing Wrong in this Code? Thank you in advance for clearing this up!

Comment: Her is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/liberationfront/aa8tsc0a/

Comment: To be in center?

Comment: How it should be: https://avexdesigns.com/responsive-youtube-embed/

Comment: You see Wire, the embedded video on this page is centered, and nicely responsive yet respecting the default size width="560" height="315"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If understood it correctly you want something like this:

```css
#embed {
    height: auto;

    text-align: center;
    background: black;
    width: 100%; /* new */
    max-width: 560px; /* new */
    margin: 0 auto; /* new */
}


.videowrapper {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}

.videowrapper iframe, .videowrapper object, .videowrapper embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section id="embed">


                  <div class="container-fluid videowrapper">

                  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/g42lHnzOeVs" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
                  </div>


</section>
```

Comment: Your correction seems right, but should it not be postioned under .videowrapper iframe ? Yet I have tryed this and it doesnt work. Watch my github page, to see what i mean. Thank you.

Comment: So I applyed your suggestion, which makes the whole section go small, but then it goes out of center. Which as i mentioned, should not be the case.

Comment: I've edited fiddle. To center it, add margin: 0 auto; to #embed.

Comment: Thnk you Wire, We are getting closer, but not yet what it should be because it adjusted the section, and not the Iframe. Now the size of video stays the same. https://bomengeduld.github.io/mos-man2/

Comment: It's a quick solution, but not solving the main issue. Because it's way smaller than  the default size width="560" height="315". I recon the solutuon should be not to adjust #embed, but to adjust the .videowrapper. What do you think?

Comment: I think you have to do it this way, because that #embed controls width and responsiveness. also remove padding, and then it will be 560. see edited fiddle

Comment: Wire, could you help with turning the background black ? So left and right from the video. The section of gallery should remain white. Because we adjusted the whole section, How can I have access to this? Should I make a parent for #embed?

Comment: As you said, make section around that, and give it background and other desired properties.

Comment: Splendid! This works very well indeed! I changed #embed into a child <div class="">