# Adapt iframe width/height to container width, Multiple iframes

Tags: css, iframe, fluid

Trying to adapt width/height.
HTML has 3 youtube videos and an article from wiki. All inserted via iframe:

```
<div class="container"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/v8ByVEM-e0g?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class="video" ></iframe><p><iframe  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XbbXJrVr8wI?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class="video"></iframe><p><iframe width="1024" height="576" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sYlKvR0j5fk?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><p><iframe width="1024px" height="10000px" src="https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4" /></p></div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
float: none;
clear: both;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 25px;
height: 0;
    }

.video {
position:absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;}
```

The result looks like the first iframe is shown, but takes up space of the following two iframes and pertially the wiki iframe. See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr6TP.jpg).

My container page is fluid itslef and needs to adapt to user device. For example, try pressing the H element and see the iframe - [chemistrytable.scienceontheweb.net/index_eng_svg.php](http://chemistrytable.scienceontheweb.net/index_eng_svg.php)

As I get it, this code works well for one video, but fails for multiple videos since all videos are taking on absolute positions and get one behind each other?

Comment: why you have p tags ? and wrongly added

Comment: Removed. Still doesn't solve.

Comment: yes it will not solve the issue, i am just wondering why you have them :)

Comment: The lame method of creating spaces between elements =) Could have used <br> or padding, but...

Answer (score 3):

first of all you've set class to container, but in css you refer to it as an id, so change that. Add some class to iframes and set its position to relative.

Here 's the example.

```css
.embed {
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.container {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
.container iframe, .container object, .container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="embed">
    <div class="container">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/v8ByVEM-e0g?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="embed">
    <div class="container">
    <iframe width="100%" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XbbXJrVr8wI?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="embed">
     <div class="container">
     <iframe width="100%" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sYlKvR0j5fk?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="embed">
    <div class="container">
    <iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried setting it as both id and class. To no avail. Setting the height to specific number still makes it fixed width, which does not adapt to container width on different types of devices.

Comment: I think you should not set fixed height, but dynamic width, so it will scale, depend on user resolution and height should be setted to keep ratio of video.

Comment: @AndrejsZavaruhins I have edited my answer, based on some of my previous answers 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249106/how-to-prevent-iframe-video-go-beyond-max-width-max-height/44249226#44249226
see if that works for you.

Comment: @AndrejsZavaruhins glad to help. Please upvote and accept answer.

Comment: Voted up yesterday. When I clicked it said something like, your vote has been accepted, but since your reputation is less than 15, they will not be publicly visible.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.embed {
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.container {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
.container iframe, .container object, .container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="embed">
    <div class="container">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/v8ByVEM-e0g?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="embed">
    <div class="container">
    <iframe width="100%" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XbbXJrVr8wI?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="embed">
     <div class="container">
     <iframe width="100%" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sYlKvR0j5fk?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="embed">
    <div class="container">
    <iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be due to the fact that you have set the IFrames to `position:absolute` instead use the CSS class

```
.video {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

When you use position: absolute; all the iframes are placed in the same position, relative to the parent `body` tag, hence you can see only one IFrame, instead, if you use `position:relative`, the IFrames will get stacked one above the other.

Hope this fixes your issue!

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Comment: Yes, I got that absolute value stacks them on top of e/o. Now, how to get them fully adapt to any width. Having height:400 px doesn't make it right. My container is fluid and needs to adapt to user device. For example, try pressing the H element and see the iframe - http://chemistrytable.scienceontheweb.net/index_eng_svg.php

Comment: @AndrejsZavaruhins From what I can see, if you set the width of the last IFrame to width:100% it will be responsive!, do not use pixel widths

Comment: Tried. Setting to width=100% and height="100%" doesn't show any video for me.

Comment: @AndrejsZavaruhins Define the height in px and width in percentage, for different screen use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) and define various heights  for the IFrame based on the screen size.

Comment: Ok. One way of doing this, but it will require returning to the project and updating media since device screen resolutuons are going up and I'm afraid those will go beyond 4k. 

Wrote to w3.org asking for a newer feature request in CSS4 or HTML6, locking video aspect ratio, something like aspect ratio="fluid". Hope they think about it.

Comment: @AndrejsZavaruhins Can you just explain the fundamental problem, just to make sure I am understanding the problem correctly?